# Why is my sponge mixture always so thick

Tags: sponge-cake

I use the classic 6 eggs, 12oz flour, sugar, butter.
Cream butter and sugar add eggs 1 at a time then a spoon of flour.

But it always comes out the consistency of a good meringue, on bake off they can almost pour their sponges mine comes in dollops. And I always think it is a bit dry.
It always rises really well.

[image: my mixture]

Comment: Are you measuring all ingredients, including the flour, by weight? Might your kitchen be unusually dry or humid?

Comment: @MarkWildon yes i measure by weight. I wish i could move to grams but 2ozs per egg is so easy to remember

Comment: It looks like you are using a stand mixer. How long are you mixing the eggs/sugar/butter? How long do you mix while adding the flour? It may be you are over-mixing and developing gluten in the flour. This would be consistent with getting a good rise. But it will make the cake less tender.

Comment: I don't see a problem here. There are hundreds of different variations for cake batter recipes, some of them producing a very liquid batter, some a very solid/mousselike one, most somewhere in the middle. The quality of the baked cake is independent of the batter consistency when raw. So there is no reason to want your batter to be more liquid, it just happens to be that way, and it's perfectly fine.